# CreateBitmap image is not printing on window

Tags: c++, windows, gdi

I need to load a bmp image from file and load image data into buffer and then create new image from it. (I have a reason for doing this way).  I wrote a sample program to mimic my project scenario.

```
     LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT Msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
     static BITMAP  bm;
     static HBITMAP bmpSource = NULL;
     static HBITMAP hbmp=NULL;
     static HDC hdcSource = NULL;
     static HDC hdcDestination= NULL;
     static PAINTSTRUCT ps;
     BITMAPINFO bitmap_info[2] = {0};

      if (Msg == WM_CREATE) {
       bmpSource = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL, L"bmp00004.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE );

       GetObject(bmpSource, sizeof(BITMAP), &bm);  

       bitmap_info->bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(bitmap_info->bmiHeader);
       int ret = GetDIBits(hdcSource, bmpSource, 0, bm.bmHeight, NULL, bitmap_info,DIB_RGB_COLORS);

       LPVOID *lpvBits = (LPVOID*) malloc(3*(bm.bmWidth * bm.bmHeight * sizeof(DWORD)));
       int gotData = GetDIBits(hdcSource, bmpSource, 0,bm.bmHeight,lpvBits, bitmap_info, DIB_RGB_COLORS);

       hbmp = (HBITMAP) CreateBitmap(bm.bmWidth, bm.bmHeight, bm.bmPlanes, bm.bmBitsPixel ,lpvBits);
        hdcSource = CreateCompatibleDC(GetDC(0));
        SelectObject(hdcSource, hbmp);
       return 0;

     }else if (Msg == WM_PAINT) {
       hdcDestination = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps); 
       BitBlt(hdcDestination, 0, 0,bm.bmWidth , bm.bmHeight, hdcSource, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
       return 0;
     }else if (Msg == WM_DESTROY) {
        DeleteDC(hdcSource);
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        DeleteObject(bmpSource);
        DeleteObject(hbmp);
     }
     return DefWindowProc(hWnd, Msg, wParam, lParam); 
}
```

I am expecting program to print the image on the window.
Now the newly created image is not displayed on window. All I can see is a gray box.

Comment: `BITMAPINFO` is a variable-sized structure. You didn't reserve enough space for the color table.

Comment: Thank you! I fixed the bug by allocating enough memory. But now the newly created image is not getting printed on window.

Comment: Then this problem is solved, and you have a new problem. You should open a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code can be considerably simplified.  There is no need to call `GetDIBits` (which you are doing before you set up `hdcSource` anyway), and you should clean up properly and minimise the use of static variables.  Something like the following (error checking omitted for clarity):

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT Msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    static HBITMAP bmpSource;

    if (Msg == WM_CREATE) {
        bmpSource = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL, L"bmp00004.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE );
        return 0;
    }

    if (Msg == WM_PAINT) {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdcDestination = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps); 
        BITMAP bm;
        GetObject(bmpSource, sizeof(bm), &bm);  
        HDC hdcSource = CreateCompatibleDC(hdcDestination);
        HGDIOBJ hOldBmp = SelectObject(hdcSource, bmpSource);

        BitBlt(hdcDestination, 0, 0,bm.bmWidth , bm.bmHeight, hdcSource, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

        SelectObject(hdcSource, hOldBmp);
        DeleteDC(hdcSource);
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        return 0;
    }

     if (Msg == WM_DESTROY)
          DeleteObject(bmpSource);

     return DefWindowProc(hWnd, Msg, wParam, lParam); 
}
```

Comment: I don't see loading image into the memory and creating image from it. The whole requirement is creating bitmap from buffer.

Comment: You don't need to do this.  You can simply draw the bitmap loaded from the file - that's the whole point of my answer, try it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are attempting to read a bitmap file and write to another `HBITMAP` handle, for whatever reason...

`LoadImage` returns a compatible bitmap (unless you specify `LR_CREATEDIBSECTION`), therefore you need `CreateCompatibleBitmap` followed by `SetDIBits` to duplicate that source bitmap.

For some reason you have declared `BITMAPINFO bminfo[2]` But you only need one `bminfo` object. You need `new` or `malloc` to allocate enough memory for one object. Note that you cannot randomly swap arrays for pointers and vice-versa. If you used a debugger you would notice the functions failed and `bminfo` was not properly filled.

It's easier if you setup `BITMAPINFOHEADER` yourself, rather than let `GetDIBits` fill that parameter:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT Msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    static HDC hdc_memory;
    static HBITMAP hbmp_src;
    static HBITMAP hbmp_dst;
    static BITMAP bm;

    if(Msg == WM_CREATE) 
    {
        hbmp_src = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL, L"file.bmp", 
                    IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE);

        HDC hdc = GetDC(0);
        hdc_memory = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);

        GetObject(hbmp_src, sizeof(bm), &bm);
        int w = bm.bmWidth;
        int h = bm.bmHeight;
        if(h < 0) h = -h;
        int size = ((w * bm.bmBitsPixel + 31) / 32) * 4 * h;
        BITMAPINFOHEADER bi = { sizeof(bi), w, h, bm.bmPlanes, bm.bmBitsPixel };
        BYTE* bits = new BYTE[size];

        GetDIBits(hdc, hbmp_src, 0, h, bits, (BITMAPINFO*)&bi, DIB_RGB_COLORS);
        //change the pixel data in bits if that's your goal ...
        hbmp_dst = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, w, h);
        SetDIBits(hdc, hbmp_dst, 0, h, bits, (BITMAPINFO*)&bi, DIB_RGB_COLORS);
        SelectObject(hdc_memory, hbmp_dst);

        delete[] bits;
        ReleaseDC(0, hdc);
        return 0;
    }
    else if(Msg == WM_PAINT) 
    {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, bm.bmWidth, bm.bmHeight, hdc_memory, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        return 0;
    }
    else if(Msg == WM_DESTROY) 
    {
        DeleteDC(hdc_memory);
        DeleteObject(hbmp_src);
        DeleteObject(hbmp_dst);
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, Msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```